# Trouble resizing XPad window on VirtualBox VM

Tags: release-loki, virtualbox

I'm running Loki inside a VirtualBoxVM

Anybody else having issues resizing XPad windows running on VirtualBox VM?

I used to be able to resize it just fine in Luna and Freya.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and right drag with the mouse.

Comment: Thank you png2378/Deni!

To resize while holding down the Control button, right click (mouse button)/drag.

To move: while holding down the Control button, left click, release mouse button.

Much appreciated!